# Inherit server block

Tags: nginx

I have several servers that I want to use all the same server block EXCEPT the location and server name(because they are different sites).

How do I do this so I don't have to duplicate(copy and page) the server blocks and then have a mess updating them all?

e.g.,

```
server { .... }  # <- Main server block

server { .... }  # <- Same as above but I can "specialize" for different properties. (listen on a different port, different server name, location, etc..)
```

Comment: hmmmm.....I don't understand what the heck you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

Use a configuration building tool such as Puppet that will interpolate strings, or if you're not willing to adopt a new tool then write a one-off generation script in the language of your choice (perl, python, shell, etc.).

You can also make use of common files and `include` statements as described in an [answer to the StackOverflow question, "nginx subdomain configuration"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9905617/90322).